# What is the evidence for North Korean famine of 1990s?

Tags: demography, north-korea

What is the evidence for North Korea famine in 1990s?

The most accounts about the famine in the Internet comes with references to US congress members who visited N. Korea, defectors or closed/unpublished estimations.

Is there any solid evidence about the famine(s) in North Korea in the 1990s?

Current life expectancy in North Korea at [68.39](http://esa.un.org/wpp/Documentation/pdf/WPP2010_Highlights.pdf) is higher than in Russia and Ukraine, although lower than in the 1990s.

Comment: [Let me Google that for you](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=1990+north+korean+famine&aq=f&oq=1990+north+korean+famine&sugexp=chrome,mod=11&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)...

Comment: @Sardathrion the Wikipedia refers to non-online Western studies. Since I have no access to them, I would like to know their sources and estimation methods. Why you downvote?

Comment: @Sardathrion If this question has a problem it is that the second paragraph waves away most legitimate sources, not that the answer is on wikipedia.

Comment: @NathanCooper: Oh yes, there is that as well but since it asks (in its original form) for references there are plenty you can follow from a simple Google search.  In my opinion, the question shows a basic lack of prior research.  If the question were to be re-formulated as per Anixx's comment to look for on-line sources of the North Korea famine(s) in 1990s and the second paragraph removed, then it would be another matter.

Comment: I'm going to vote to close. If you're going to exclude all testimony that references US Congressmen, then you're not practicing history, you're practicing politics.  Besides the sources that @Sardathrion cites include [According to diplomats, United Nations officials and a variety of non-government organizations, North Korea stands yet again on the brink of a major food shortage.](http://www.time.com/time/world/article/0,8599,1737780,00.html). Unless the all diplomats and NGO's are tainted by association with US Congressmen.

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace do you mean the US congressmen are a reliable and objective historical source? What about N Korea People's assembly members? Well my question was created so to find out whether there any evidence beyond the claims by selected politicians.

Comment: @Sardathrion Okay, I think you're correct. I think Anixx should improve the question. Also Anixx shouldn't state false equivalences between DPRK officials and US senators. I do think a broadly similar question should exist, wikipedia is not the be all and end all and in it's citations lack a perspective from the Chinese border. Also rejecting given that the answer is contained in the citation of the wikipedia page (rather than the page itself) seems a bit harsh for this site.

Comment: @Sardathrion no, my question is what the evidence for the famines besides the claims by interested politicians (US senators) and defectors (who are obviously interested). That is I am looking for verifiable evidence.

Comment: @NathanCooper: Yes, wikipedia is not an authoritative source but might contain such. Thus, it is as good as starting point as any. I do object to not showing that one has done a minimal amount of research first.  Note that a first comment mentioned *what are the positions of North Korea and China on the famines* but a simple Google search yielded the answers.

Comment: @Sardathrion I did not ask for positions of N Korea and China.

Comment: typical Anixx, anything not coming from communist sources is rejected on general principle...

Answer (score 6):

I'm sorry to throw a PhD dissertation at you. But I believe [Food shortages and economic institutions in the Democratic Peoples' Republic of Korea](http://wrap.warwick.ac.uk/2505/) addresses your concerns. From page 168 (179 on the freely viewable pdf). Addresses whether there was a famine using the accounts you have hinted at as well as UN figures, with comparison to official DPRK figures. It looks at the evidence we have for their production, their consumption of food aid, amost other things.

edit: The sources he's used that I've looked at are UNICEF, ROK figures (probably not what you wanted) and NGO figures like the KBSM below.

Some of the data used but not given can be found in [Forced Migration and Mortality](http://www.nap.edu/openbook.php?record_id=10086&page=71). The abstract is of interest but too long to post, here is some of it:

*Buddhist Sharing Movement (KBSM) released a report on the North Korean food crisis based on interviews with North Korean migrants in China ... FIGURES HERE... “that the worst famine in human history is now transpiring in North Korea” (Korean Buddhist Sharing Movement, 1998).
Concerned by these accounts but unable to assess the reliability of their findings, a U.S. nongovernmental organization (NGO) active in North Korean humanitarian relief, Mercy Corps International, invited the Johns Hopkins School of Public Health to undertake its own study of North Korean migrants in China. In the past five years, significant numbers of North Koreans have been moving across the Chinese border in search of food for themselves and their families. It is estimated that between 50,000 and 150,000 North Koreans are staying temporarily in China...*